# Combination of R Shiny and Darksky API Error

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to develop a simple application using R Shiny and Darksky API. My objective is to utilize dateInput widget (R Shiny) in order to show Temperature, Wind Speed, Cloud Cover and Precipitation Probability forecast(from Darksky API) for the selected date. This is what I got so far:

**ui.r file**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
   fluidPage(
      titlePanel( title = "UAS Flying Protocol"),
      sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(strong(h2("Menu")),
               dateInput("dat",strong("Date:"),value= Sys.Date()),
               submitButton("Submit")             
         ),
         mainPanel((strong(h2("Main Panel"))),
            plotOutput("myPlot", width = "100%", height="1000px")
        )
      )
   )
)
```

**server.r file**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(darksky)
shinyServer(
    function(input,output) {
        darksky_api_key(force = TRUE)
        dt1<-renderText(as.character(input$dat))
        x<-get_forecast_for(39.091648, 26.549723, units="si", dt1)
        dt2<-cbind("T00:00:00+0200")
        dt3<-paste0(dt1,dt2)
        x<-get_forecast_for(39.091648, 26.549723, units="si", dt3)
        z<-data.frame(Temperature = as.numeric(), PrecipitationProbability = as.numeric(), CloudCover = as.numeric(), WindSpeed = as.numeric())
        z<- data.frame(Temperature = x$hourly$temperature, PrecipitationProbability = x$hourly$precipProbability, CloudCover = x$hourly$cloudCover, WindSpeed = x$hourly$windSpeed)
        output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
            p1<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$temperature)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Temperature",x="Hour", y = "Temperature in Celsius")
            p2<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$PrecipitationProbability)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Precipitation Probability",x="Hour", y = "Probability in %")
            p3<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$CloudCover)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Cloud Cover",x="Hour", y = "Cloud Cover in %")
            p4<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$WindSpeed)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Wind Speed",x="Hour", y = "Wind Speed in KmPH")
            grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 1)
        })
    }   
)
```

And this is the **error** i get in the console:

> Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
>   Stack trace (innermost first):
>       40: as.character.default
>       39: as.character
>       38: paste0
>       37: server [C:\Users\mbats\Google Drive\Michaela_fly_protocol\r_script\apptest/server.R#14]
>        1: shiny::runApp
>   Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
>     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

I can't understand where exactly the error is. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Shiny, a reactive value/output means a piece of code that gets re-run each time the input changes. An example is a graph (like in your case) which is updated depending on input. This is different from regular code such as creating a button with words which only needs to happen once and doesn't change. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) for more info. The takeaway is you can only access reactive values in a reactive context.

All the `render` functions are used to output a UI result, and they create a reactive context, i.e. a place where you can access reactive values such as anything starting in `input$`. Note that you can have multiple lines of code in there, as long as the final line gives what you need for that component (so a `grid.arrange`d ggplot in your case).

So `input$dat` needs to be called inside `renderPlot`, and you can move all the other lines into there as well. Also, you can just use `input$dat` without `renderText` (which is returning a function/closure for a UI text field to be updated).

**server.r file**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(darksky)
shinyServer(
    function(input,output) {
        output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
            darksky_api_key(force = TRUE)
            dt1<-as.character(input$dat)
            #x<-get_forecast_for(39.091648, 26.549723, units="si", dt1)
            dt2<-cbind("T00:00:00+0200")
            dt3<-paste0(dt1,dt2)
            x<-get_forecast_for(39.091648, 26.549723, units="si", dt3)
            z<-data.frame(Temperature = as.numeric(), PrecipitationProbability = as.numeric(), CloudCover = as.numeric(), WindSpeed = as.numeric())
            z<- data.frame(Temperature = x$hourly$temperature, PrecipitationProbability = x$hourly$precipProbability, CloudCover = x$hourly$cloudCover, WindSpeed = x$hourly$windSpeed)
            p1<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$temperature)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Temperature",x="Hour", y = "Temperature in Celsius")
            p2<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$PrecipitationProbability)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Precipitation Probability",x="Hour", y = "Probability in %")
            p3<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$CloudCover)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Cloud Cover",x="Hour", y = "Cloud Cover in %")
            p4<-ggplot(z, aes(x=as.numeric(rownames(z)), y=z$WindSpeed)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(title="Wind Speed",x="Hour", y = "Wind Speed in KmPH")
            grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 1)
        })
    }   
)
```

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you very much for your help and guidance!

Comment: Great to hear :)